# passing data attribute to fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to have it where when someone clicks on an image that displays in a fancybox I want to pass the product_url data attribute to Fancybox for something like a download link.

I have setup a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/erbtdp24/) for testing but cant seem to get it to work.  I will have multiple images with fancybox on a page and each one will have their own data-product_url attribute.

```
<a rel="gallery" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin imperdiet augue et magna interdum hendrerit" class="fancybox" 
   href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg" 
   data-product_url="http://google.com">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

<a rel="gallery" title="Proin imperdiet augue et magna interdum hendrerit" class="fancybox" 
   data-product_url="http://yahoo.com"
   href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">
<img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" alt=""/></a>

$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function() {
        var url = $(this, '[data-product_url]');
        this.title = '<a href="' + url + '">Download</a> ' + this.title;
    },
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(this.element).data("product_url")` instead of `$(this, '[data-product_url]');` to get this elements data tag and you 'll be fine.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t0qfs015/1/)